# Generate WCF classes for multiple WSDL files with inlined XSD and reuse classes

Tags: .net, wcf, xsd, wsdl

I have few WSDL files (and I'll be getting more of them in future irregularly) with inlined XSD with many shared XSD types (repeated in each WSDL). I need to think out a process how to process these WSDLs and reuse generated classes with as little manual work as possible. The easiest solution I was thinking about would generate each class into separate file, which would ensure distinct classes.

I already tried svcutil.exe with the reuse option, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. There's also problem with inheritance (XmlIncludeAttribute for serialization) - each WSDL contains just part of whole inheritance hierarchy.

So it looks like I need to take all the WSDLs I have at the moment, extract XSD out of them, merge those XSDs into one big XSD and generate C# classes from this merged XSD file.

Is there any proven solution for this kind of problem? I'd appreciate any tips'n'tricks..

Answer (score 0):

We have had a similar problem, svcutil produced one very large CS file with all the classes in it.

We used Resharper to split the file into individual class files.

The svcutil reuse option only works if you have dll's with the classes in the xsd.

You could do it like this:

- Place each wsdl in its own directory
- run svcutil on each
- use resharper to split the files
- copy all files to single directory, with skip of files with duplicate name

Comment: Unfortunately this is not viable solution, because there is the inheritance hierarchy problem I mentioned in my question. Each WSDL contains just part of inheritance hierarchy tree, so I need to merge those types together somehow...